# different packages same topics

Tags: ros, 3rd-party-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi every one, I am new to ROS and Masters student.
We have two packages in the same work space. I want to use a subscriber node in Package1 to a subscribe to a topic published by a node in Package2.
Actually we are doing work on DJI done. DJI has provided their SDK. We want to simulate our algorithms on Matlab and create a package for our algorithm using matlab coder. Then we want to combine matlab coder generated nodes with the nodes provided by DJI SDK. Is it possible.?
We are considering matlab algorithm as Package1 and DJI SDK as Package 2. So matlab package node would subscribe to DJI  SDK nodes to get data and  process this data. So is it possible..?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240571/different-packages-same-topics/) by [UsmanArif](https://answers.ros.org/users/27566/usmanarif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-07-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2016-07-28**:
There is a [matlab implementation of ROS](http://uk.mathworks.com/hardware-support/robot-operating-system.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) so that should be fine. I don't know DJI, in the worst case you might have to write a wrapper for that. But maybe someone else knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for helping :). But my question is that, can i run two different packages at the same time in ROS.?? The Package1 has a subscriber node which is subscribing to a topic initiated by a publisher of Package2....?
If yes What should i do perform communication between two packages at same time..?

---

Originally posted by [UsmanArif](https://answers.ros.org/users/27566/usmanarif/) with karma: 41 on 2016-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-28**:
Yes; you can publish a topic from a node in one package and subscribe to that topic from a node in a different package.